# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in ... 32 line

Tags: php, wordpress

При попытке активации темы wordpress ругается на ошибку в 32 cтроке. Вот эта строка... Что тут не так? На сервере версия php 7.0 если что.

```
if((!empty( $_POST['featured_image'])
    && $_POST['featured_image'] == $file['name'])
    || (empty( $_POST['featured_image'])
    && empty(get_post_thumbnail_id( $_POST['advert_id'])))){
```

Подскажите как исправить сей нюанс?

Comment: `На сервере версия php 7.0 если что` - стоит перепроверить. И ещё раз перепроверить, выведите `var_dump(phpversion());` Ошибка характерна для вызова функции из аргумента empty на версиях до PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: Да уж... То что говорит человек, и то что оказывается на самом деле разные вещи... Позвонил на хостинг, действительно версия 5.45... Спасибро

Comment: @Мелкий ответы - в ответы )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такая ошибка была характерна до версии PHP 5.5.0 при попытке вызова функции из языковой конструкции `empty`. `empty` именно конструкция языка, а не функция, поэтому у неё было такое ограничение. Но начиная с PHP 5.5.0 вызов вида

```
empty(get_post_thumbnail_id( $_POST['advert_id']))
```

стал легитимным.

Поэтому стоит перепроверить, какой именно версии PHP у вас выполняет этот скрипт. Например, добавить где-то выше этого условия вывод версии:

```
var_dump(phpversion());
```

Для современных версий PHP условие выглядит нормально.

Comment: Другое дело) Плюсанул

Comment: Аналогично :) ))